# Realm: How to query only the objects of a father in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, android, realm

I have the following problem:

`Father` containing a `RealmList<Kid>` (with `Kid` being another RealmObject)

I would like to query a list of all `Kid`s belonging to `Father`, without querying `Father` itself, via:

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(Kid.class).equalTo("fatherId", id);
```

But I'm pretty certain that this is not possible, as `Kid` has no reference to `Father`.

Do I have to query the `Father` object and then call the `getKids()`method?

If you're wondering why I'm not simply querying `Father`: I have a generic method for querying, querying any class given to it:

```
public <T extends RealmObject> List<T> getForFather(Class<T> clazz, String fatherId)
```

Most of the classes queried belong to `Father` and I want to avoid if-else statements. I also would like to avoid multiple methods doing the same thing, just with another class. Above generic method would work, but only, if there's a way to query `Kid` for a specific `Father`.

Comment: [`Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(` this opens Realm instances that are never closed, and will eventually cause you trouble](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149)

Comment: It was just an example, I do create local variables, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case,
you have to use the conventional method of design the ER for the database.

That is,
Instead of having `RealmList<Kid>` in your `father` object create a `primaryKey` in the `father` and have the reference of that primary key in child `fatherPrimaryKey`

then you can simply query

```
RealmResults<Kid> result = realm.where(Kid.class).equals("fatherPrimaryKey", "some_key").findAll();
```

And while storing the data in the kid object, make sure you pass the correct value of `father's primary key` to the child as reference.

Comment: That is actuallyy too much of a hassle to keep track of. I think I'll just query the user and call the necessary getters. But thanks for the answer. :)

On a side note: Is there a way to filter a RealmList with a "Between"-Filter?